# How to determine constant $C$ in $p(x) = Cx^{-D}$?

Tags: statistics, optimization, fractals, chaos-theory

Given a distribution obeying the power-law (fractal) relation, such as the cumulative distribution function $L_{cf}(> X) = CR^{-D}$, if $X$ is given, how does one find the constant $C$ from a given data set?

For example, given this table:

[image: Source: C. Li et al. / Geomorphology 130 (2011)]

[Source: C. Li et al. / Geomorphology 130 (2011)]

how does one determine how the values for $L_{cf}$ were obtained? It appears that they used the method of least squares fitting to obtain the values for $D$, but I don't seem to understand where the values for $C$ are coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship between $R$ and $L_{cf}$ is
$$
L_{cf}=C R^{-D}\tag1,
$$
then logging both sides of (1) gives you
$$
\log(L_{cf})=\log C -D\log R.\tag2
$$
Read equation (2) this way: If you plot $\log(L_{cf})$ on the $y$-axis against $\log R$ on the $x$-axis (equivalently, if you plot $L_{cf}$ against $R$ on log-log paper), you should see a straight line. Moreover, the slope of that line will be $-D$, and the $y$-intercept will be $\log C$. From these two bits of information you can deduce the values of $D$ and $C$.

(The authors found two piecewise linear segments, each with its own parameters that can be deduced in this way. [Interesting paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251528573_The_power-law_relationship_between_landslide_occurrence_and_rainfall_level), btw. The data seem to fit, ahem, remarkably well.)

Comment: But if $C$ and $D$ are unknown, and $L_{cf}$ is to be found as well, then how can we even plot the log-log function without knowing $C$ and $D$?

Comment: $L_{cf}$ is the cumulative distribution function of the rainfall distribution. In other words, for each value of $R$ you need to compute $L_{cf}(>R)$ from your data. Then plot all pairs of $(R,L_{cf})$ obtained this way. They will form a scatter plot that you will fit a straight line to (in log-log space).

Comment: Can you please give an example of how that works? Say, I have $R=112$. How does that help me in my plot?

Comment: The value for $L_{cf}$ when $R=112$ is the proportion (%) of landslides that occurred at rainfall level greater than 112 mm.  Now you plot $(R, L_{cf})$ for this value of $R$, and repeat for all other values of $R$. Fig 11 in your paper has four plots of this form; they've only shown a few pairs of $(R, L_{cf})$ in each plot

Comment: So, does one need to know the percentage of landslides occurred above $R$ in order to do the plot? The issue is that it doesn't seem clear how to calculate $L_{cf}$ without knowing $C$ and $D$ in the first place. Or should one just use the known percentage of landslides which have occurred under a certain level of rainfall? Looks like I had confused what had to be found with what was already known.

Comment: You calculate $L_{cf}$ as the *empirical* (data-based) percentage. The relation $L_{cf}=CR^{-D}$ is then fit to the data. So you don't need to know $C$ and $D$ to compute $L_{cf}$. You just need to tally the distribution of $R$, across all landslides, into a histogram (as in Fig 9 of your paper). For each observed value $r$ of $R$, $L_{cf}(>r)$  is then the percentage of your histogram that's to the right of $r$.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought Thank you for clarifying this.